# Joining two tables on decimal (longitude/latitude) columns is *slow*

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables each with fields Label, Latitude, Longitude. I want to pull out the two labels where the latitudes and longitudes match. This would create new table Label1, Label2, Latitude, Longitude.

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, Round(Latitude2,5) AS Expr1, Round(Longitude2,5) AS Expr2,Round(Latitude1,5) AS Expr3, Round(Longitude1,5) AS Expr4 INTO Merge
FROM [Table1], [Table2]
WHERE (((Round(Latitude2,5))=Round(Latitude1,5)) AND ((Round(Longitude2,5))=Round(Longitude1,5)));
```

This appears to put me in to a loop and I'm pretty sure I understand why, but can't quite figure out how to get what I want.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your query, although not elegantly written, should be doing what you want.  Because you have functions on the columns (`round()`), the query cannot take advantage of indexes (if you have any).  So this is rather hard to optimize.

Comment: It seems to freeze though, I've let it go for a few minutes. Each table has about 50,000 records, and not all will match. Could this cause a problem? Should I give it more time?

Comment: It depends whether you have more than one of the same latitude and longitude matching up on these tables.  You could get more rows than you want.  Let's say you have (forgive my not real lattitudes and longitudes) lat, long 1,1 showing up with 3 different labels in table 1. and lat, long 1,1 showing up with 4 different labels in table 2.  Your join would give you back 12 records joining each to each in every combination.

Comment: That is a possibility, and maybe I am trying to make this more simple than it is. I may have to approach this spatially, grabbing any labels with lat,longs near the other. --Edit Having 12 labels in one location would not cause me a problem other than making my table too large/slow.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments to the question, the fact that you are using the `Round()` function in the join conditions means that the database engine cannot use any indexes on the Longitude and Latitude fields (if such indexes even exist). This could very well be the cause of the poor performance you are experiencing.

I have a test case with two tables, each table having 5,000 rows. The structure of [Table1] is

ID - Autonumber, Primary Key
Longitude1 - Double
Latitude1 - Double
Label1 - Text

The structure of [Table2] is the same, except that the fields are named [Longitude2], [Latitude2], and [Label2].

When I run the query you posted in your question, it takes 10 minutes to complete.

To speed things up, I added two more fields to each table: [intLon] and [intLat], both of them defined as Long Integer and indexed. They were populated like so:

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET
    intLon = Round(Longitude1, 5) * 100000,
    intLat = Round(Latitude1, 5) * 100000

UPDATE Table2 SET
    intLon = Round(Longitude2, 5) * 100000,
    intLat = Round(Latitude2, 5) * 100000
```

Once that is done we can get the same results as the initial query by using

```sql
SELECT Label1, Label2, Round(Latitude2,5) AS Expr1, Round(Longitude2,5) AS Expr2,Round(Latitude1,5) AS Expr3, Round(Longitude1,5) AS Expr4 INTO Merge
FROM 
    [Table1] 
    INNER JOIN 
    [Table2] 
        ON Table1.intLon = Table2.intLon 
            AND Table1.intLat = Table2.intLat
```

but instead of taking 10 minutes to execute it takes 0.8 *seconds* to run.